# Calculate how long person was on his job, with pandas DataSet and python

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I got stuck with my data and pandas.

My data looks like this:

```
| User ID | User Name | Addr            | Date       | Time  |
|---------|-----------|-----------------|------------|-------|
| 1       | Jon       | Prod.Entry In   | 2022.11.21 | 12:00 |
| 1       | Jon       | Prod.Exit  Exit | 2022.11.21 | 16:00 |
| 2       | Josh      | Main.Entry In   | 2022.10.10 | 13:00 |
| 1       | Jon       | Prod.Entry In   | 2022.10.10 | 12:00 |
| 1       | Jon       | Prod.Exit  Exit | 2022.11.09 | 16:00 |
| 2       | Josh      | Main.Entry In   | 2022.10.09 | 13:00 |
```

etc...

It's dataset from card chek-in and chek-out system
Now I need to calculate how long user was absent and how long he was present on his job.
So I need to substrate Exit time from enter time to calculate how long he was present.
Also from "next Entry time" I need to substrate "last Exit time" to calculate absence of worker
(for example if he was too long on pause)
So basically I need formulas like this:
"Prod.Exit Exit" - "Prod.Entry In" or "Main.Entry In" - "Main.Entry Exit"

So that's all clear but only I need help and idea how to:
1.iterate through this data set
2.get times and substract them, one by one, and then first and last
3.show them in form of columns 'absence time', 'present time'
4.How to minimize error's because some worker check in a few time's in a row or he exit without check out

I tried something like this:

```
entries = {'user_id': [], 'Date': [], 'Time': []}
exits = {'user_id': [], 'Date': [], 'Time': []}

for (df['User ID'], df['Date']) in df.iteritems():        
        if (df['Addr'] == 'Main Entry-In' or 'Prod. Entry-In'):
            entries['user_id'].append(df['User ID'])
            entries['Date'].append(df['Date'])
            entries.['Time'].append(df['Time'].values)
        if (df['Addr'] == 'Main Entry-Exit' or 'Prod. Exit-Exit'):
            exits['user_id'].append(df['User ID'])
            exits['Date'].append(df['Date'])
            exits['Time'].append(df['Time'].values)
```

but of course I got stuck and confused...
I am sure that there is more simple and better way to do this

please help

Comment: I assume that your check in must be check out, so you can consider sorting the data by date, then by time. Then with this, the first checkout data that is after the index of the check in data is definitely the checkout datetime of the check-in.

Comment: Not really, I need to iterate trough users and dates to get Times and then calculate delta between check in and check out  of that specific user on specific day, to calculate how long he was on job, and how long he was absent from job :)